# ZModo Cameras - read camera signal

Tags: surveillance-cameras

I recently bought a zmodo camera, namely the ZP-IBH15-W. I'm noticing they disabled the webapp and support a PC and Mobile App. However I'm looking for a way to view the image through a standard protocol and do some processing.

Is there a way to extract information using a standard way that can be programmed? I'm thinking something in python similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891936/rtsp-stream-and-opencv-python.

Comment: `support a PC and Mobile App`  ..... use a PC and run wireshark to sniff the data .... then try to figure out the protocol .... https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: thank you. I have wireshark running and see communnication is running on port 8000 on the remote device. Need to dig deeper.